# Interface for a modifiable list

Tags: java, list

So I have an interface:

```
public interface
{
    List<String> getList();
}
```

However, I believe that the implementer can return an unmodifiable list like:

```
List<String> getList()
{
    return Collections.unmodifiablelist(new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

Is there any interface, or a way to ensure than a modifiable list is always returned. I don't want to have to make a copy.

Comment: Try to modify it, and create a copy if it throws UnsupportedOperationException? Or you could just require `getList()` returns `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: No, you can _never_ stop a class which implements your interface from throwing a `RuntimeException` which is what that list will do

Comment: Document the existing interface, saying that a modifiable list is expected. Exception otherwise..

Comment: Call it `getModifiableList` and blame whomever implemented your interface incorrectly.

Comment: As a side note, you should _really_ think carefully about this. If the implementer returns an unmodifiable list, perhaps there's a reason? Maybe their internal implementation depends upon that list...and you modifying it externally will cause issues? Perhaps the better approach is to expose an _add_ method in your interface, which your implementers can use to add an item to their list (then you _never_ modify it outside of the class)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assure because the return type is `Collection`.What you can do is a proper doc.

> In terms of API design, you should just make your javadoc clear ! People who use a method without reading its doc deserve the surprise.

[Is it acceptable to return unmodifiableList or should I return array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186045/is-it-acceptable-to-return-unmodifiablelist-or-should-i-return-array)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is not a interface but a especific implementation, because an interface defines "how thing supose to be" not "how things are". In other worlds, you are trying to establish a especific a behave, so, the best way here is to force the implementers to use a especific version of `List`, like this:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    MyModifiableList getList();    

}
```

And then, you create your version of a modifiable class that will be used by your implementers. For exemple:

```
public final class MyModifiableList {
     // Implementation...
}
```